# jquery dropline to hold second when mouse is hover out

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, hover

Is there a way to get this behavior on [this dropline menu](http://jsfiddle.net/ljuboja/DxpMJ/)?Need second or thrid level to stay active for one second when mouse is hover out from menu items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, you're looking for some kind of delayed reaction to the mouse's movement? If so, check out this jQuery hoverintent plugin: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

**EDIT:** I think you'll need to edit your menu script to replace any instance of .hover with .hoverIntent. I had trouble testing this in jsfiddle, but see if it works:

```
var droplinemenu={

arrowimage: {classname: 'downarrowclass', src:'http://www.odzaci.rs/wp-content/themes/typo/images/down.gif', leftpadding: 5}, //customize down arrow image
animateduration: {over: 200, out: 300}, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds

buildmenu:function(menuid){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var $mainmenu=$("#"+menuid+">ul")
        var $headers=$mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
        $headers.each(function(i){
            var $curobj=$(this)
            var $subul=$(this).find('ul:eq(0)')
            this._dimensions={h:$curobj.find('a:eq(0)').outerHeight()}
            this.istopheader=$curobj.parents("ul").length==1? true : false
            if (!this.istopheader)
                $subul.css({left:0, top:this._dimensions.h})
            var $innerheader=$curobj.children('a').eq(0)
            $innerheader=($innerheader.children().eq(0).is('span'))? $innerheader.children().eq(0) : $innerheader //if header contains inner SPAN, use that
            $innerheader.append(
                '<img src="'+ droplinemenu.arrowimage.src
                +'" class="' + droplinemenu.arrowimage.classname
                + '" style="border:0; padding-left: '+droplinemenu.arrowimage.leftpadding+'px" />'
            )

            // THIS IS THE PART I REPLACED

            var config = {    
     over: function(e){
            var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
            if ($targetul.queue().length<=1) //if 1 or less queued animations
                if (this.istopheader)
                    $targetul.css({left: $mainmenu.offset().left, top: $mainmenu.offset().top+this._dimensions.h})
                if (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest) //detect IE6 or less, fix issue with overflow
                    $mainmenu.find('ul').css({overflow: (this.istopheader)? 'hidden' : 'visible'})
                $targetul.slideDown(droplinemenu.animateduration.over)
        },
timeout: 1000, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
out: function(e){
            var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
            $targetul.slideUp(droplinemenu.animateduration.out)
        }
};

$curobj.hoverIntent( config );




        }) //end $headers.each()
        $mainmenu.find("ul").css({display:'none', visibility:'visible', width:$mainmenu.width()})
    }) //end document.ready
}
}
```

Comment: thx for answer, but I cant figure out how to incorporate this plugin into this script.Confuse me what selector to use, trying few selectors but with no success.Im try with hoverIntent with configuration object, but with no results.Make call to external script in my header(hover intent script), and than in script tag added script code from plugin page mention above.Nothing happen, when mouse is out of menu links there no delay of 500ms(submenu dissapear momentaly) like in example on plugin page.What is the problem?

Comment: work great, tnx
Can you see this, pls Im stack also with  this:-(
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622659/mixing-jquery-dropline-and-dropdown-menu)