# Mixing jquery dropline and dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

How to achive that following [menu](http://jsfiddle.net/ljuboja/DxpMJ/) act normaly like dropline, but last sublevel to be dropdown instead dropline?
Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure I understand the question, are you wanting the sub-drop-downs to display in a vertical list instead of horizontally? If so, try adding this to your CSS:

```
.droplinebar > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li
{
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

**ADDENDUM** (to get the menus lined up properly):

I haven't tested this, but see if changing line 16 to the following does the trick:

```
$subul.css({left:$curobj.position().left, top:this._dimensions.h})
```

You may need to do something like the above on $targetul as well.

**2nd ADDENDUM**

It's a bit dirty, but you can always give the sub-ul's a unique id, and them use css to line then up manually.

http://jsfiddle.net/DxpMJ/11/

In that example, I gave a unique id to the JavaScript > Traveling 4 menu, and manually set the margin-left and overrode the width with the !important trick (which you should look up if you're not familiar with it - very useful when javascript plugins are setting CSS styles without your knowledge). If you don't mind manually adding css rules for all of the menus you need to be vertical, I think this would work.

Comment: yes, this is what I want.Just now link in vertical list are totaly on left side and have huge background.How to set links appear just below parent link, not far left?
tnx

Comment: I don't think this menu plugin is going to support what you are trying to do without modifying a lot of code. I'd recommend looking at some of the menus here and find one that does what you want without having to make modifications to it: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Comment: This menu is on wordpress.Spent hours of tweaking to work like  I want, Oh man this been so close:-(

Comment: I don't necessarily think you should give up on it... I encourage you to dig in and start tweaking things, just for the experience if nothing else. Manipulating .postition() values of $targetul as well as $subul might also be necessary. I'm afraid I don't have time to look into it in more depth, but I hope you've got a good start for doing some trial and error.

Comment: Thx for help and your time, this take me so close to end of my misery with this menu.I dont wanna take your time and bother you anymore.But just one hint to give me.Is it possible to get result that I want only with css?My js not good :-(If  not, could you push me in right direction before I dive in trial and error with $targetul and $subul: wich values I can use and how sintax will look with one arbitrary example.I hope that is not to much of me to ask.Best regards.

Comment: Try my second addendum... Also, just curious, when I edit my answer, do you get a notification, or do I need to add a new comment for you to see the notification?

Comment: Thank you very much!Work well with css.
Save me of headache!
 notification I didnt pay attention on this.You can edit your answer pro forme, than I pay attention and give you feedback